# Cannot open database “dataname" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, crash, visual-studio-2019

I have created a windows app, But I am getting this error:

> Cannot open database "dataname" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user.

using integrated SQL Server Authentication.

My connection string is

```
Dim ConStr As String = "Server=192.168.36.72 ; Database=Library;User ID=sa;pwd=scc1234*;Trusted_Connection=True; Integrated security=sspi;"
```

Comment: You aren't using SQL Server Authentication. You're trying to with the User ID = pwd = etc but they're being over-ridden by Integrated Security=sspi (Windows Authentication). The clue is in the user named in the error. It is NOT "SA" (the ID in the connection string is SA). Remove the integrated security part and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

In package manager console

```
add-migration first
update-database
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this from the connection string:

```
Integrated security=sspi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me:

1. Right click on database project in Solution Explorer and choose "Publish"
2. Click "Edit" target database connection in "Publish Database" window
3. Choose your database and click OK
4. Copy the appeared string in "Target database connection" and use it as connection string